# Is there a linux distro that uses Jack audio server all the time?

Tags: linux, audio, desktop, jack

By this I mean a distro that does not use pulse audio at all. So when you are runing programs like `miro` or `mumbles` you do not lose audio playback becuase Jack took over the audio stack.

Comment: Just don't install pulseaudio?

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/) should be what you're looking for. It's a *multimedia oriented* distro based (obviously) on Ubuntu which uses a **realtime kernel** and the **JACK Audio Connection Kit**.

Answer (score 1):

[puredyne](http://puredyne.org/) is made specifically for multimedia applications based on Ubuntu and Debian Live that can run from a CD or DVD, but it does not automatically start up Jack.

There are several other distros for multimedia production, but as far as I know, none of these start Jack by default, and I do not know the state of development on these distros, so I include these just for completeness:

- [Musix](http://www.musix.org.ar/en/index.html)
- [64 Studio](http://www.64studio.com/)
- [dyne:bolic](http://www.dynebolic.org/)

A different solution would be to tell Pulseaudio to run on top of Jack, if you are inclined to do some editing on your config files: http://trac.jackaudio.org/wiki/WalkThrough/User/PulseOnJack